# Change UIImageView of other class

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

Working on that for days and I don´t find a solution. I have two classes. In the first one I´ve got an

```
IBoutlet UIImageView *image
```

I´d like to change this image if a certain function is called in a second class.

```
[image setImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"MainDesign_Iphone_17.png"]];
```

doesn´t work in the second class because "image" is not known there. How can I do it?

---

#### EDIT:

My .h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController{


}

@property (strong) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;

@end
```

My .m in second class

```
#import "SecondClass.h"
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface SecondClass ()

@end

@implementation SecondClass


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [ViewController.imageView setImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"MainDesign_Iphone_17.png"]];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

Make this:

```
IBOutlet UIImageView *image;
```

into a property like this:

```
@property (strong) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;
```

in the class's "`.h`" implementation file.

Notice that I also changed the name from "`image`" to "`imageView`", since calling an imageView an image is confusing.  An  image view *contains* an image.

Now that you've declared it as a property and not as a private ivar, you can access the image view from your second class by doing something like:

```
[firstClass.imageView setImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"MainDesign_Iphone_17.png"]];
```

And obviously you would replace the word "`firstClass`" with whatever way you refer to  one class from the other.

Comment: I think you mean [firstClass.imageView setImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"MainDesign_Iphone_17.png"]]; as the image (a UIImage) property of the UIImageView will not have a setImage: method :)

Comment: riiiiiight.  Thanks Will!

Comment: Thank you.But I get "Property "imageView" not found on object of type "firstClass"" (I changed the class Name).

Comment: where did you put your "`@property`" declaration?  Should be in the .h file and make certain to reconnect your IBOutlet connection in your storyboard or XIB file, while you're at it.

Comment: The property should be public..means it should be defined in .h file itself

Comment: My property is in the .h file between (at)interface... and (at)end. I cant put my code in this comment area nor I can answer my own question to show you my code :(

Comment: you can edit your original question to show what you're now doing.

Comment: Does someone has an idea? I really stuck at that. I tried it with all kinds of IBoutlets. Nothing works. It must be a small silly mistake. I can´t get access of the image!

Comment: How does your SecondClass object get the address or object of your ViewController object?  Unless "`ViewController`" is a singleton, you cannot do "`ViewController.imageView setImage:`" in your SecondClass the way you are.  Also, you should rename "`ViewController`" something more intuitive and explanatory.